# Buscar una palabra en una matriz leyendo de derecha a izquierda

Tags: c

Estoy intentando el siguiente programa: el usuario introduce una palabra y se deberá encontrar en una matriz leyendo de izquierda a derecha o de derecha a izquierda. 
He conseguido que encuentre las palabras leyendo de izquierda a derecha, pero no de derecha a izquierda.

He probado dos métodos: el primero creando un string 'del revés' al string original y leyendo la matriz de manera normal y el segundo método, utilizando un string igual al introducido pero leyendo la matriz de derecha a izquierda.

Sin embargo, ninguno de los métodos funciona.

Método 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 5
#define M 7

void mostrar_sopa(char sopa[N][M]);
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col);
int cad_iguales (char pal1[], char pal2[]);
int longitud_pal (char pal[]);

void main()
{
    int fila, columna;
    char pal[M];

    char sopa[N][M] =
    {
        'A', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'A', 'P',
        'B', 'N', 'O', 'T', 'R', 'P', 'Y',
        'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'W',
        'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'T', 'A',
        'E', 'T', 'O', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'Y',
    };


    mostrar_sopa(sopa);

    printf("\nIntroduce una palabra, de %d caracteres como maximo: ", M);
    gets(pal);


    for(fila=0; fila<N; fila++)
    {
        for(columna=0; columna<M; columna++)
        {
            if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==1)
                printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la derecha", fila, columna);

            else if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==2)
                printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la izquierda", fila, columna);
        }
    }

}

//calcula la longitud de una palabra que recibe como parámetro
int longitud_pal (char pal[M])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; pal[i] != '\0'; i++);

    return i;

}

//compara dos palabras que recibe como parámetros,
// devuelve: 1 si son iguales y 0 si no lo son
int cad_iguales (char pal1[M], char pal2[M])
{
    int i, enc=1;

    for(i=0; pal1[i]!='\0' && pal2[i]!='\0' && enc; i++)
    {
        if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i])
            enc=0;
    }

    return enc;
}

//Función que permite al usuario mostrar la sopa de letras centrada
void mostrar_sopa(char sopa[N][M])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("                        ");

        for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            printf("%2c", sopa[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//Busca la palabra horizontalmente a partir de una posición de la matriz que
//recibe como parametro
//Devuelve 0 si no la ha encontrado, 1 si la encuentra de izquierda a derecha y 2 si la encuentra de derecha a izquierda
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col)
{
    int i, j, resul=1, resul2=2;

    char pal2[M+1], pal3[M+1];

    for(i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        pal2[i]=sopa[fil][col+i];
        pal3[i]=pal2[longitud_pal(pal2)-i];
    }

    if(cad_iguales(pal, pal2)!=1)
        resul=0;

    if(cad_iguales(pal, pal3)!=1)
        resul=0;

    return resul;
    return resul2;

}
```

Método 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 5
#define M 7

void mostrar_sopa(char sopa[N][M]);
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col);
int cad_iguales (char pal1[], char pal2[]);
int longitud_pal (char pal[]);

void main()
{
    int fila, columna;
    char pal[M];

    char sopa[N][M] =
    {
        'A', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'A', 'P',
        'B', 'N', 'O', 'T', 'R', 'P', 'Y',
        'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'W',
        'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'T', 'A',
        'E', 'T', 'O', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'Y',
    };


    mostrar_sopa(sopa);

    printf("\nIntroduce una palabra, de %d caracteres como maximo: ", M);
    gets(pal);


    for(fila=0; fila<N; fila++)
    {
        for(columna=0; columna<M; columna++)
        {
            if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==1)
                printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la derecha", fila, columna);
        }
    }

    for(fila=0; fila<N; fila++)
    {
        for(columna=M-1; columna>=0; columna--)
        {
            if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==1)
                printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la izquierda", fila, columna);
        }

    }
}

//calcula la longitud de una palabra que recibe como parámetro
int longitud_pal (char pal[M])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; pal[i] != '\0'; i++);

    return i;

}

//compara dos palabras que recibe como parámetros,
// devuelve: 1 si son iguales y 0 si no lo son
int cad_iguales (char pal1[M], char pal2[M])
{
    int i, enc=1;

    for(i=0; pal1[i]!='\0' && pal2[i]!='\0' && enc; i++)
    {
        if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i])
            enc=0;
    }

    return enc;
}

//Función que permite al usuario mostrar la sopa de letras centrada
void mostrar_sopa(char sopa[N][M])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("                        ");

        for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            printf("%2c", sopa[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//Busca la palabra horizontalmente a partir de una posición de la matriz que
//recibe como parametro
//Devuelve 0 si no la ha encontrado y 1 si la encuentra
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col)
{
    int i, j, resul=1;

    char pal2[M+1];

    for(i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        pal2[i]=sopa[fil][col+i];

    }

    if(cad_iguales(pal, pal2)!=1)
        resul=0;

    return resul;


}
```

Por ejemplo, si yo escribo 'PAP' (fila 0, columna 6) solo detecta cuando empieza desde la columna 4 (hacia la derecha). Y si escribo 'ATI'(fila 3, columna 6) no lo detecta.

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques preguntas. Edita la pregunta original para añadir nueva información y contenido.

Comment: @Alvaro, ¿cuál es la _pregunta original_ a la que se debió añadir? si esa pregunta original existe, creo que es momento de cerrar esta, para mantener el orden de las mismas.

Comment: @jachguate la [pregunta original](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9329/encontrar-palabra-en-sopa-de-letras-horizontalmente) se cerró como duplicado porque ésta tenía respuestas y la otra no.

Comment: Gracias @Alvaro, un saludo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas verás que `buscar_palabra_horizontal()` no es capaz de buscar de izquierda a derecha. Únicamente realiza búsquedas de derecha a izquierda. De hecho una prueba de ello es que realizas exactamente la misma llamada para ambos casos. Lo único que cambia es que las columnas las recorres en sentido directo en un caso y en sentido inverso en el otro... pero la llamada a `buscar_palabra_horizontal()` es exactamente la misma:

```
if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==1)
  printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la derecha", fila, columna);

if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==1)
  printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la izquierda", fila, columna);
```

Una opción es añadir un parámetro adicional a dicha función para indicar el sentido, por ejemplo un enumerado. De esta forma puedes dirigir el sentido en el que el algoritmo trata de localizar las palabras:

```
typedef enum Sentido
{
  DerechaAIzquierda,
  IzquierdaADerecha
} Sentido;

int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col, Sentido sentido)
{
  int sopaIndex= 0;
  int offset = 0;

  switch( sentido )
  {
    case DerechaAIzquierda:
      colIndex= col;
      offset = -1;
      break;

    case IzquierdaADerecha:
      sopaIndex= 0;
      offset = 1;
      break;
  }

  for(int i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++, sopaIndex += offset)
  {
    pal2[i]=sopa[fil][sopaIndex];
  }

  // ...
}
```

EDITO: Por otro lado, centrándonos en tu primera solución tenemos:

```
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col)
{
  int i, j, resul=1, resul2=2;
  char pal2[M+1], pal3[M+1];

  for(i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    pal2[i]=sopa[fil][col+i];
    pal3[i]=pal2[longitud_pal(pal2)-i];
  }

  if(cad_iguales(pal, pal2)!=1)
    resul=0;

  if(cad_iguales(pal, pal3)!=1)
    resul=0;

  return resul;
  return resul2;
}
```

Cosas raras que hay en esta función:

- Tiene dos return seguidos, lo que implica que únicamente se ejecutará el primero.
- La variable `resul2` no tiene ningún uso real.
- La variable `j` no se usa.
- Siempre que se encuentre una palabra devolverá el mismo resultado, 0, independientemente de si la palabra la ha encontrado a derechas o a izquierdas, lo que te impide saber desde fuera el sentido de la palabra.
- El condicional de `cad_iguales` lo estás complicando en exceso. Si `cad_iguales` únicamente te va a devolver 1 o 0 el condicional se puede simplificar.
- No estás teniendo en cuenta los límites de `sopa`. ¿Qué sucede si estoy en la columna 4 e intento leer en sentido dcha->izda una palabra de 5 letras? ¿Y si la intento leer en sentido izda->dcha?
- `pal2` y `pal3` no están inicializadas. Eso unido a la forma en la que copias las cadenas no garantizas que las mismas terminen con '\0'.

Función corregida:

```
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col)
{
  int resul=0; // 0 -> no se encuentra la palabra
  char pal2[M+1], pal3[M+1];

  memset(pal2,M+1,0);
  memset(pal3,M+1,0);

  for(int i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
  {
    pal2[i]=sopa[fil][col+i];
    pal3[i]=pal2[longitud_pal(pal2)-i];
  }

  // Sentido izda->dcha, si se encuentra la palabra se devuelve 1
  // cad_iguales devuelve 1 si encuentra la palabra y 0 en caso contrario
  result = cad_iguales(pal, pal2);

  if( result == 0 )
  {
    // Si cad_iguales devuelve 1 -> palabra encontrada de dcha->izda
    // 1*2==2 -> palabra encontrada dcha->izda
    // 0*2==0 -> palabra no encontrada
    result = cad_iguales(pal, pal3)*2;
  }

  return resul;
}
```

Solo faltaría revisar si intentas leer fuera de los límites de `sopa`, pero eso ya corre de tu cuenta.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿No se podría conseguir con un método parecido al método 2 que he puesto? ¿Utilizando dos cadenas y que la segunda sea el reflejo de la primera, y llamando con el valor 2?

Comment: Podría funcionar pero tendrías que controlar los límites de la _sopa_ para no leer fuera de tu fila. Además, `pal3[i]=pal2[longitud_pal(pal2)-i]` debería ser `pal3[i]=pal2[longitud_pal(pal2)-i-1]` para no poner el '\0' al inicio de la cadena invertida.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero sigue sin funcionar. He probado una funcion que enseñe qué sale cuando igualo pal3 a pal2 y aparecen caracteres erróneos. 
¿Quizá el problema esté ahí? No entiendo por qué aparecen caracteres erróneos si la igualación es correcta.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta, es demasiado largo para explicarlo en un comentario.

Answer (score 0):

*Esta propuesta de código funciona correctamente, la he comprobado ...*

**En *buscar_palabra_horizontal* ...**

**1º** Se han de inicializar **pal2** y **pal3** para evitar cualquier posible fallo inesperado, inicializar las variables es una buena práctica de programación.

**2º** Si lo que resta de substraer la columna **col** al tamaño de una fila **M**,
es menor que el tamaño de la palabra, esta no podrá estar contenida en esa posición, por lo que se deberá devolver 0, antes de continuar procesando.

**3º** - Para poder copiar **pal2** invertido en **pal3**, primero se tiene que haber copiado completamente **sopa[fil][col+i]** en **pal2[i]**, por lo que se debe completar primero ese bucle y luego efectuar el segundo, puesto que este último ha de empezar por asignar el último char, y este no puede copiarse en el primer ciclo del primer bucle, en el cual **pal2** solo contiene su primer elemento asignado. Por ello usaremos dos bucles.

**4º** Para poder copiar **pal2** invertido en **pal3** a la expresión que pusiste, hay que *restarle 1*, pues sino trataría de copiar en primer lugar el tamaño de **pal2 - i** (siendo que i vale 0 en el primer ciclo) y esto estaría fuera del rango de indice de la cadena de **pal2** (al ser exactamente su tamaño (de cadena), lo excede en 1).

**5º** Para que los resultados se procesen de forma funcional hay que anidar los if, se han de asignar los resultados esperados en **resul** (0 : No concuerda,1 : a derecha o 2 : a izquierda ).

**En *Main* ...**

**6º** A los resultados (filas y columnas) hay que sumarles 1 a la fila y 1 a la columna, para que devuelvan - filas y columnas -, en lugar de sus índices; Y cuando es *a izquierda* se le ha de sumar a las columnas el tamaño de la palabra para que indique la columna de la primera letra de la palabra invertida (puesto que se lee de derecha a izquierda).

**· · *C ó d i g o* - *c o m p r o b a d o* · ·**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 5
#define M 7

void mostrar_sopa(char sopa[N][M]);
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col);
int cad_iguales (char pal1[], char pal2[]);
int longitud_pal (char pal[]);

void main()
{
    int fila, columna;
    char pal[M];

    char sopa[N][M] =
    {
        'A', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'A', 'P',
        'B', 'N', 'O', 'T', 'R', 'P', 'Y',
        'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'E', 'W',
        'A', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'T', 'A',
        'E', 'T', 'O', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'Y',
    };


    mostrar_sopa(sopa);

    printf("\nIntroduce una palabra, de %d caracteres como maximo: ", M);
    gets(pal);


    for(fila=0; fila<N; fila++)
    {
        for(columna=0; columna<M; columna++)
        {
            if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==1)
                printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la derecha", fila+1, columna+1);

            else if(buscar_palabra_horizontal(sopa, pal, fila, columna)==2)
                printf("\nEsta en la fila %d y en la columna %d: hacia la izquierda", fila+1, columna+longitud_pal(pal));
        }
    }

}

//calcula la longitud de una palabra que recibe como parámetro
int longitud_pal (char pal[M])
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; pal[i] != '\0'; i++);

    return i;

}

//compara dos palabras que recibe como parámetros,
// devuelve: 1 si son iguales y 0 si no lo son
int cad_iguales (char pal1[M], char pal2[M])
{
    int i, enc=1;

    for(i=0; pal1[i]!='\0' && pal2[i]!='\0' && enc; i++)
    {
        if(pal1[i]!=pal2[i])
            enc=0;
    }

    return enc;
}

//Función que permite al usuario mostrar la sopa de letras centrada
void mostrar_sopa(char sopa[N][M])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("                        ");

        for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            printf("%2c", sopa[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//Busca la palabra horizontalmente a partir de una posición de la matriz que
//recibe como parametro
//Devuelve 0 si no la ha encontrado, 1 si la encuentra de izquierda a derecha y 2 si la encuentra de derecha a izquierda
int buscar_palabra_horizontal(char sopa[N][M], char pal[M+1], int fil, int col)
{
    int i, resul=1, resul2=2;

    char pal2[M+1]="", pal3[M+1]="";

    if (M-col<longitud_pal(pal))
       return 0;

    for(i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
        pal2[i]=sopa[fil][col+i];

    for(i=0; pal[i]!='\0'; i++)
        pal3[i]=pal2[longitud_pal(pal2)-i-1];


    if(cad_iguales(pal, pal2))
        resul=1;
    else if(cad_iguales(pal, pal3))
        resul=2;
    else resul = 0;

    return resul;
}
```